# Delays in updating content controls when more context.sync() are used on WORD for Mac

Tags: macos, office365, office-js

We update content control for every character typed in the task pane’s input field. So that user can see the live updates on the word document.

Recently we added functionality for locking content controls. And it happens as below:

- User input (types a character) in a input field
- We search a content control for that input field (involves context.sync)
- Unlock the content control (involves context.sync)
- Update value in content control (involves context.sync)
- Lock back the content control (involves context.sync)

All this works nice in Word for windows without problems. 
But is extremely (visibly) slow with Word for Mac (apple machines)

How should I overcome the delays happening on Mac?

Comment: Hello I need more details for this. a) I what Mac builds are you experiencing this? how many content controls are you updating? c) scenario-wise why are you blocking/unblocking the content control on each key-down on the task pane? wont be better to wait until the user tabs out to block it?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.
I agree on (c) and will update my scenario with focus-in and focus-out.
But Still I see delays as compared to Word for windows. Details 
- Updating one content control (some times 2-3) at a time by its tag name.
- Word for Mac 15.36 (170702)
- Mac Os 10.12.6

Comment: A sample snippet will also be helpful and also try Michael's suggestion below

Answer (score 0):

As Juan mentioned in the comment, there are some important details that the team would need to investigate.  Sample code would be good too.

That being said, just looking at what you describe, I think you can dramatically cut down on the `context.sync()` statements.  Unlocking the content control, updating its value, and locking it should all be possible to do in one `sync`.

I have a bunch of details about minimizing `sync`-s in my book, "[Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins).  Quoting one of the sections from it:

> As an add-in author, your job is to minimize the number of `context.sync()`
>   calls. Each sync is an extra round-trip to the host application; and when
>   that application is Office Online, the cost of each of those round-trip adds up
>   quickly.
>
> If you set out to write your add-in with this in principle in mind, you will
>   find that you need a *surprisingly small number of `sync` calls*. In fact, when
>   writing this chapter, I found that I really needed to rack my brain to come up with a scenario that *did* need more than two `sync` calls. The trick for
>   minimizing sync calls is to arrange the application logic in such a way that
>   you're initially scraping the document for whatever information you need
>   (and queuing it all up for loading), and then following up with a bunch
>   of operations that modify the document (based on the previously-loaded
>   data). You've seen several examples of this already: one in the intro chapter,
>   when describing why Office.js is async; and more recently in the "canonical
>   sample" section at the beginning of this chapter. For the latter, note that the
>   scenario itself was reasonably complex: reading document data, processing
>   it to determine which city has experienced the highest growth, and then
>   creating a formatted table and chart out of that data. However, given the
>   "time-travel" superpowers of proxy objects, you can still accomplish this task
>   as one group of read operations, followed by a group of write operations.
>
> Still, there are some scenarios where multiple loads may be required. And in
>   fact, there may be legitimate scenarios where even doing an extra sync is the
>   right thing to do – if it saves on loading a bunch of unneeded data. You will
>   see an example of this later in the chapter.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot in general. Still, there is noticeable difference between how it performs with windows and Mac.